# Vercel serverless function has crashed error

Tags: javascript, cloud, hosting, vercel

I am trying to host my express api on vercel

And this error occured

> This Serverless Function has crashed

It tried everything to fix it but nothing worked

Any help ?

I don't know why this error is happening and i tried everything

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.